# how to sign in bar file for BB 10 (with android)

Tags: android, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-10, blackberry-android

Hello i have tried to sign in bar files for that i have done following stage

First Windows - > Preferences - > Blackberry - > Blackberry Tools SDK - > Bar signer

IN that i have certified apps

it will look like below

[image]
Right Click on android project- > Blackberry tools -> SignIn for APP world

Now You can see the bar file is generated without any error it will looking like below

[image]

but when i make zip of this bar file and try to upload on blackberry app world i m getting error like this

c[image]

can anybody suggest me how to resolve this error because i have already signed with certificate but still i am getting error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the BAR file with WinZip/WinRar and check if there is META-INF folder. Inside you should find 5 files (if the BAR is signed correct).

Once you verify that the BAR is signed correct you can upload manual the BAR file (and not using ZIP file with Batch Import files option).

Scroll down the Add Release page and click on Add file bundle, enter bundle name, choose platform QNX, Min Supported version 10.0.0, select All touch as supported devices and upload the BAR file.

Comment: hi i m getting no any file from there is just one file named MANIFEST.MF

Comment: Try to sign the app with the online packager https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/android/bpaa/ This way you can verify if the signing keys are installed correct